# Android turns landscape even when setOrientation is set to portrait only

Tags: android, orientation

I've set

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

On manifest and it works well... till keyboard appears. When keyboard is shown you can turn the orientation to landscape and my webview refresh the entire application making the user to log in again. I don't want (or need) a savestate, only block entire features that can refresh the app when changing orientation. I don't need or want the app to being able to turn on landscape. I'ts completely usable on portrait only and was designed to it.

It's supposed that `android:configChanges="orientation"` tells android that the app will take care about orientation, and `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` blocks the phone to enter landscape mode when running the app, but keyboard seems to override this config.

At this point i can't figure out how to achieve this workaround,

thanks

**SOLVED:**

I tried 
     android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"

and now it works. I found this line on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) but at first sight i thought that i may have to handle keyboard show/hide after setting keyboardHidden on the configChanges but it's working fine with this options, the keyboard appears when user interacts with an input field but it's not able to show in landscape or turn the app to landscape.
I've also set screenSize and screenLayout as documentation linked avobe recommends.

I'll mark this question as solved when i can. Thanks

Comment: I'll close it when i can, in two days. If anyone want to answer, should read the question, including the SOLVED part...

Comment: Not answering your question, but you said "I don't want (or need) a save state", which is wrong. The fact that you only want your app to use portrait orientation is not a good reason to completely ignore saving and restoring state. Configuration changes can happen for many other reasons, and state can also be lost when the system kills your app. Please handle it for the sake of your users.

Comment: It's a webview so the "state" of user actions will remain in the server. There's no need or point on saving state here. It's a 12Kb weight app, I can't find a reason to put more code here for saving state or wharever.

Comment: Also there's no camera, mic, speakers or any sensor access, the user interacts only with keyboard and the layout should only show on portrait mode. That's all, simply and clear.

Answer (score -1):

save the state.

```
private static final String STATE_COUNTER = "counter";

   private int mCounter;
private ArrayList<Item> mItems;


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
// Make sure to call the super method so that the states of our views are saved
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
// Save our own state now
    outState.putInt(STATE_COUNTER, mCounter);
// Save our own state now
outState.putSerializable(STATE_ITEMS, mItems);
}
```

then restore the state again

```
private static final String STATE_COUNTER = "counter";

private TextView mCounterTextView;
private int mCounter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// If we have a saved state then we can restore it now
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCounter = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_COUNTER, 0);
    }

// Display the value of the counter
    mCounterTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter_text);
    mCounterTextView.setText(Integer.toString(mCounter));

...
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_COUNTER, mCounter);
}
```

hope you find the answer.

Comment: I already solved it without saving the state. There's a non sense on saving state on a low weight apk designed for portrait. Setting the proper options on manifest did the trick.